# A log file isn't getting created and written into in my Mojolicious app

Tags: perl, logging, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I have this in my Mojolicious app:

```
  use utf8;
  use Mojolicious::Lite;
  # ......
  use Mojo::Log;

  my $app = app;
  my $log = Mojo::Log->new(path => '/var/log/my_log.log', level => 'warn');

  get '/' => sub {

    .........

    $log->info("test123");

  }

  app->start;
```

The log file didn't even get created. 
After some time I created it myself, made it "chmod 777" and now it's still not being written into.

Why?

Comment: Did you restart the app after you created the file chmod'd 777?

Comment: If you only have the level `warn` you'll not get anything in the log but warnings or higher. The system does `info`, and you are doing `info` in your code. It doesn't need to write to the log, so it doesn't.

Comment: @simbabque I've removed level => 'warn' and now it should be info by default. But it still isn't logging anything

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes

Comment: @Dada if it's debug by default, it should work in any case then

Comment: Firstly, `Mojo::Log` will not create the log file until something is written to it. Secondly, are you aware that you need to access the URL for your app for the `$log->info` call to happen? Are you doing that? It would be much easier just to call `$log->info` when `$log` is first created then inside one of the path handlers.

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce your error: if i remove the `level => 'warn'`, it works. (if I have the permissions to access the file) Could you show us a minimalistic reproducible example and tell us exactly what you do to call the sub that is supposed to log? (for starter, remove the  `....`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to associate the log with your app (reference https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious#log)

```
my $log = Mojo::Log->new( path => '/var/log/my_log.log', level => 'warn' );

app->log($log);
```

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that `$log` is created with level `warn`, so `info` messages don't show.